# StreamPhysicalOverAggregate doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Deduplicate

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have sql like this and i get this error `StreamPhysicalOverAggregate doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Deduplicate(keep=[LastRow], key=[id], order=[PROCTIME])`.

I am create this view `identity_entitlement_source_keyed` so that flink sql can use this to partition data correctly.

I am using flink 1.17.1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE identity_entitlement_poc /** mode('streaming')*/ (
 `id` string,
 `entitlementAssignments` ARRAY<ROW<nativeIdentity STRING, sourceID STRING>>,
 `eventTime` AS PROCTIME()

)
with (
 'connector' = 'kafka',
 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:29092',
 'properties.group.id' = 'identity-entitlement-local-1',
 'topic-pattern' = 'identity_entitlement_poc',
 'format' = 'json',
 'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
 'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
 'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
 'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'

);


create or replace view /*TODO identity_entitlement_source_keyed__dbt_tmp*/ identity_entitlement_source_keyed  as (
  
SELECT r.*
FROM (select r.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY eventTime DESC NULLS LAST) AS row_num -- todo add pod and org here
    FROM identity_entitlement_poc r) r
WHERE row_num = 1
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE identity_entitlement_sink (
                
      /** mode('streaming')*/
  
  id STRING, entitlementAssignments ARRAY<ROW<`nativeIdentity` STRING, `sourceID` STRING>>, previous_value ARRAY<ROW<`nativeIdentity` STRING, `sourceID` STRING>>

  
      ,PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED )
  

WITH (
  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka','key.format' = 'json',
  'key.json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
  'value.format' = 'json',
  'value.json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
  'topic' = 'identity_entilement_sink_2',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:29092'
);
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: The inclusion of "NULLS LAST" looks suspicious to me. Have you tried it without that?

Comment: Remocing `nulls last` did not work. I still get the same error